# Is there is any why to pass array of error messages to toastr js.i want to show multiple toastr messages using array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, toastr

> anyone have any solution?

*controller Details*

**this is controller where multiple error message generated in for loop**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
           var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                var confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "AccountRoles",
                                        new { userId = user.Id, token = token }, Request.Scheme);
               

            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                TempData["msg"] = error.Description;
            }


            return View(model);
        }
```

**js**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var a = '@TempData["msg"]';
                if (a != '')
                    toastr.error(a)    
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop in your controller method does not generate an array of error messages.
The line `TempData["msg"] = error.Description` is repeated in the loop which means that in your javascript calling `@TempData["msg"]` will result in only retrieving the last error message.

You need to generate a list of error messages and then store them in TempData.

```
TempData["msg"] = result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description).ToList();
```

And then in javascript, you loop over the resulting array and display an error message for each one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var errors = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(TempData["msg"]));
    errors.forEach(x => toastr.error(x));
});
```

Comment: thanks for you descriptive and to the point answer